# Javascript interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

As I know very little about Javascript and Jquery I am hoping to be able to get an answer here.

Here is the code in my `<head></head>` of my document.

```
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var current_shouts = 0;
            function $(eleid) {
                return document.getElementById(eleid);
            }
            function urlencode(u) {
                u = u.toString();
                var matches = u.match(/[\x90-\xFF]/g);
                if (matches) {
                    for (var mid = 0; mid < matches.length; mid++) {
                        var char_code = matches[mid].charCodeAt(0);
                        u = u.replace(matches[mid], '%u00' + (char_code & 0xFF).toString(16).toUpperCase());
                    }
                }
                return escape(u).replace(/\+/g, "%2B");
            }
            function shouts() {
                clearTimeout(getshout);
                var xmlHttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                xmlHttp.open("GET", "../shoutbox/shouts.php?i=" + Math.random());
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {
                        if (parseInt(this.responseText) > current_shouts) {
                            getshouts();
                            current_shouts = parseInt(this.responseText);
                        }
                        getshout = setTimeout("shouts()", 1000);
                    }
                }
                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }
            function getshouts() {
                var xmlHttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                xmlHttp.open("GET", "../shoutbox/getshouts.php?i=" + Math.random());
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4) $("shoutbox").innerHTML = this.responseText;
$("shoutbox").scrollTop = $("shoutbox").scrollHeight;
                }
                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }
            function push_shout() {
                shout();
                return false;
            }
            function shout() {
                var xmlHttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                xmlHttp.open("POST", "../shoutbox/shout.php");
                var data = "user=" + urlencode($("user").value) + "&" + "shout=" + urlencode($("shout").value);
                xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4) {
                        if (!this.responseText) $("shout").value = "";
                        else {
                            $("console").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                            setTimeout("$('console').innerHTML = ''", 5000);
                        }
                        getshouts();
                    }
                }
                xmlHttp.send(data);
                return true;
            }
            var getshout = setTimeout("shouts()", 1000);
</script>
```

It seems when I put the typed code above everything, it does not work, but the others do, if the code sits as it is shown above it works, but the scripts above it do not work anymore.

I have tried `$.noConflict();` but it seems it did nothing, so I am not sure what I am to do here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you check if your .js file paths are correct? Can you post any error messages you received?

Comment: why are you overriding $() if you are using jquery? function $(eleid){}. If you have jquery manually setting up ajax calls also doesn't make much sense because you can use the cross browser method of $.ajax().

Comment: agree with @scrappedcola, if you already have jQuery, then why duplicate functionality. Writing stuff from scratch is one thing, but you obviously already have jQuery there that's meant for exactly what you're doing (DOM lookup, AJAX calls).

Comment: your use of $(console) would be better off as the default jquery function via $("#console"). Then you can set the html with $("#console").html(this.responseText); There are more things, but your code makes my head hurt...

Comment: @scrappedcola Like I said I don't know much about JS so I don't really know what you are referring to. I did not write that piece of code, and without knowing anything about the language it is hard for me to change it in a way that fixes any issues at this time.

Comment: if you simply want to know how to avoid conflicts of the $ then you might have a simple solution. However this code sample is like a textbook case of bad practices.  So unless you want to take on a big task of figure out why, you probally just need to knwo more aobut the conflict.   $ is the alias for the jQuery object.   If you use noConflicts it removes this alias sot hat other libraries that want to use it can.  inorder to use jQuery without conflicts you would simple either give it another alias or references the logn hand way as jQuery.ajax etc.

Comment: So basically all of the $'s in the code is what is causing the issues? I mean I want to learn to do this the right way, not just an easy way out, so any tips on what I should read up on to do this the right way would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

then you can use `$j` to refer to the jQuery object whenever you need to.

Comment: @kira423 youre welcome! and not to be a self-promoter, but if this answer fixed the problem would you mind accepting it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with jQuery plugins clashing somehow.
I loaded both into the head of the html document, between consecutive separated script tag zones. Then I used:

`window.onload = function() {function01(); function02();};`

to load each function in an orderly fashion and separately.

It worked for me this time.

Comment: this answer doesn't seem very well related to the question, please provide more detail on how it helps.